# How to add a table inside a div with its CSS working

Tags: html, css

I have a fiddle which contains a table.The table contains css effects to make HTML table look good.Now i want to add this table inside a div.At present inside div i am opening jquery dynamic Tab and i want this my table to get added below the dynamic Tab..

Here is my HTML table fiddle link..

[HTML table fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/UL2AG/)

And here is my div and dynamic tab HTML ..

```
 <div id="main" style="float: left; width:83%; margin-left:5px; margin-top:0px;">
<div id="doclist">
        </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="tabs">
        <!-- Tabs go here -->
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- Tab content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="links" style="float:left; margin-left:0px; position: absolute; margin-top:180px">

<label name="" id="" style="font-style:normal; font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;"> </label>

  <br/><br/>
 <ul id="documents">
  <li><a href="#" rel="Document1" title="This is the content of Document1"></a></li>
<br/>
  <li><a href="#" rel="Document2" title="This is the content of Document1"></a></li>
<br/>
 <li><a href="#" rel="Document3" title="This is the content of Document1"></a></li>
<br/>
<li><a href="#" rel="Document4" title="This is the content of Document1"></a></li>
<br/>
<li><a href="#" rel="Document5" title="This is the content of Document1"></a></li>
<br/>
<li><a href="#" rel="Document6" title="This is the content of Document1">Cancelled Reservation List</a></li>
<br/>
<li><a href="#" rel="Document7" title="This is the content of Document1">Check Out Pending List</a></li>
<br/>
<li><a href="#" rel="Document8" title="This is the content of Document1"></a></li>
<br/>
<li><a href="#" rel="Document9" title="This is the content of Document1"></a></li>
<br/>
<li><a href="#" rel="Document10" title="This is the content of Document1"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And here is my css..

```
    body { font-family:Lucida Sans, Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size:13px; margin:0px auto;}
    #tabs { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; overflow:hidden; }
    #tabs li { float:left; display:block; padding:5px; background-color:#bbb; margin-right:5px;}
    #tabs li a { color:#fff; text-decoration:none; }
    #tabs li.current { background-color:#e1e1e1;}
    #tabs li.current a { color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
    #tabs li a.remove { color:#f00; margin-left:10px;}
    #content { background-color:#e1e1e1;}
    #content p { margin: 0; padding:20px 20px 100px 20px;}

    #main { width:1050px; height:500px; margin:0px auto; overflow:hidden;background-color:#F6F6F6; margin-top:0px;
         -moz-border-radius:10px;  -webkit-border-radius:10px; padding:5px;}
    #wrapper, #doclist { float:left; margin:0 0px 0 0;}
    #doclist { width:150px; border-right:solid 1px #dcdcdc;}
    #doclist ul { margin:0; list-style:none;}
    #doclist li { margin:10px 0; padding:0;}
    #documents { margin:0; padding:0;}

    #wrapper { width:930px; margin-top:0px;}

    #header{ background-color:#F6F6F6; width:900px; margin:0px auto; margin-top:20px;
         -moz-border-radius:10px;  -webkit-border-radius:10px; padding:30px; position:relative;}
    #header h2 {font-size:16px; font-weight:normal; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
```

So my question is how to add fiddle table inside the div with all its effects ..

This is the refrence files that i have added..

```
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="plugins/ui.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="plugins/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What else i need to add?

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hsakapandit/UL2AG/355/

Comment: @mrdeveloper i updated my post with the reference files added .I think i have missed something what is that?Please tell me sir

Comment: @mrdeveloper http://jsfiddle.net/UL2AG/356/ this is my updated fiddle .Sir please tell me what reference files i need to add in my application

Comment: Download http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js file and add in js reference

Comment: @mrdeveloper jquery 1.11.1.min.js is deplacing my contents of the web page and result is still same only .No styling in the table

Comment: Do you want output same as in your fiddle or some changes?

Comment: Also dont forget to link http://jqueryui.com/ files in your page

Comment: @mrdeveloper I am trying it on my end sir..

Comment: @mrdeveloper which files i need to include from jquery ui files that i downloaded?

Comment: Download stable version of Jquery UI and link all files in your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your jquery library file to the latest version of JQuery library.

You are using JQuery 1.5 which is very old and might not support Jquery UI

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js